# AngularJS - ng-init w/ ng-repeat not working but hidden div does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

Any idea how to get this to work?:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in editable_values" ng-init="val = edit_data[item]">
```

From what I can tell, `val` is always `undefined`, based on `{{val}}` not displaying anything. I'm guessing that `ng-init` is running when `editable_values` is defined, but I actually need it to run when `edit_data` changes.

This does work, but feels hacky:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in editable_values">
    <div ng-show="false">{{val = edit_data[item]}}</div>
```

`editable_values` is a list of keys

`edit_data` is an object

`editable_values` is defined at creation time in the controller, while `edit_data` isn't defined until the user clicks on something to edit. The div that acts as a container for the `ng-repeat` in question isn't actually visible until a user clicks on something to edit.

The `ng-repeat` used to be `(item, val) in edit_data`, but I needed to sort the keys in a specific order.

Comment: Why are you even setting a `val` variable? - Just access the object when you need to.

Comment: From ng-init documentation --> `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.` Why do you need to use ng-init. Can you show us the minimal required code to fully understand the context.

Comment: The purpose of val is to avoid having edit_data[item] repeated 7 times. In this particular case, to avoid having to search/replace existing code to something less readable.

Comment: The context is that I used to have a (key, value) loop, but the alphabetical ordering of the keys was unacceptable, so I needed my own ordering. This resulted in the loop changing from iterating based on edit_data to iterating based on editable_values. I suppose one option is to have a variable which points to either `null` or `editable_values` when `edit_data` is set, and then loop on that, but that seems like a needlessly complex solution to this problem when the hidden div is simpler and more straightforward.